# How to get file path or upload_id with ipfs.addAll()

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, ipfs, js-ipfs

I have progress UI which gets files path and updates progress by file upload_id. But in ipfs.addAll function is not returning id or something to show correctly progress. I mapped files to progress id it repeats every time not working as expected. How I can fix it?

```
for await (const result of ipfs.addAll(fileContent, {
   progress: (progress) => {
     map(files, (item) => {
      dispatch(
       uploadActions.uploadChangeProgress({
        progress,
        id: item.upload_id,
      })
    )
  })
},}))
```

Comment: Are you having trouble associating the progress update with the specific file being uploaded? Or is it not working even for one file?

Comment: I having trouble associating the progress update with the specific file being uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the [js-ipfs docs for `addAll`](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#ipfsaddallsource-options), it mentions there's a second parameter to the `progress` callback.

> a function that will be called with the number of bytes added as a file is added to ipfs and the path of the file being added

So add that as an argument to your callback to differentiate the files:

```js
for await (const result of ipfs.addAll(fileContent, {
   progress: (progress, filePath) => {
      dispatch(
       uploadActions.uploadChangeProgress({
        progress,
        id: filePath, // (unless this needs to be the actual IPFS file ID?)
      })
    )
  })
},}))
```